# Integrar Bootstrap en Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel

Estoy iniciando con Laravel y tengo problema al ligar las rutas de `Bootsrap`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    {{ HTML::style('assets/css/bootstrap.min.css', array('media' => 'screen')) }}
    <!-- <link href="{{ asset('assets/css/bootstrap.min.css')}}" rel="stylesheet"> -->

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
@include('partials.navbar')
    <div class="container">
        @yield('content')
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Primary</button>
    </div>

    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js">
    </script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src={{ url('/assets/js/bootstrap.min.js')}}></script>
</body>
```

Y no consigo que lo ligue, con el `link` no me manda error pero no carga los estilos y con `HTML::style` me manda:

> Class 'HTML' not found

Esta es la estructura de mi proyecto.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Versión de Laravel?

Comment: Te podria ser util https://styde.net/integrar-bootstrap-3-en-laravel-5-1/

Comment: Error porqué no tienes la clase `HtmlServiceProvider` agregada a **providers**  y tampoco  su alias en **aliases** en la configuración de tu App

Comment: Ya estuve leyendo el link que puso @J.Castro pero ¿Podria ligarlo sin usar ´HtmlServiceProvider´ ? Muchas gracias por sus comentarios.

Comment: Sí, como si fuera html "normal", algo similar a como hiciste con el script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para agregar el link a un recurso dentro de `Public` solemos usar:

```
<script src="{{asset('components/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js')}}" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

donde el directorio es:

> Aplicacion/public/components/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js

puedes ver la documentación sobre [asset](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/helpers#method-asset)

#### EDIT

Veo que en la imagen los ficheros de bootstrap (el marco de trabajo web) está en la carpeta "bootstrap" de Laravel. La carpeta `Bootstrap` del directorio principal de Laravel no es para mantener scripts ni hojas de estilos relacionados al cliente. Esta es una traducción del uso de este directorio:

> #### El Directorio bootstrap
>
> El directorio bootstrap contiene archivos que inicializan el framework y configuran el autoloading. Este directorio también contiene el caché generado por el framework para la optimización del rendimiento.

En [Bootstrap directory, Laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/structure#the-bootstrap-directory)

Comment: Hola, tengo una pregunta, yo hago lo de tu respuesta y eh investigado y esa parece ser la solución, pero no me carga y al darle clic al link de css que me genera, me aparece **Esta página no funciona**

Comment: Cuál es la ruta que te genera Laravel? Y cuál es la ruta real del css?