# Integrar Materialize css en Laravel 5.4

Tags: css, laravel, laravel-5, materialize

Alguien me podria decir como instalar, materialize css en mi proyecto hecho en **laravel**? Actualmente estoy trabajando con la version **5.4 de laravel**
Hago esta pregunta, porque se que viene con bootstrap instalado cuando haces un nuevo proyecto.
Si alguien sabe como hacerlo y me refiero a **descargar los archivos** y ponerlos en mis carpetas correspondientes y no llamarlos con la dirección url de la propia pagina de materialize.
De ante mano muchas gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La verdad que es bastante simple lo que quieres, tan solo necesitas poner los archivos de Materialize en la carpeta public, en la subcarpeta correspondiente:

- Los archivos de CSS normalmente van en `public/css`
- Los archivos de JS normalmente van en `public/js`

A continuación referencias los archivos en tu vista, probablemente una vista parcial, puedes usar [LaravelCollective](https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.3/html):

```
{!! Html::style('css/materialize.css) !!}
```

O también lo puedes hacer de la forma típica HTML:

```
<script src="/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
```

Tal y como es sugerido en un comentario, el helper [asset()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/helpers#method-asset) también funciona en este caso:

```
<script src="{{ asset('js/materialize.min.js') }}"></script>
```

Comment: Otra de las formas es usando `asset` como en [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/60062/4617) :P

Comment: Muchas gracias Shaz!
Me resulto como dijiste y pues, en asset deje todos los archivos funciona igual gracias